# Can a class call another function in a class without the firstclass needing to know the class that is it

Tags: java, class, networking, handler, packets

So I might have worded the question badly so I will try to explain what I mean. So i have a game server that interfaces with unity written in java and I was wandering if there was a better way of handling the received TCP stream data. Then someone suggested that I use dynamic packet handling which is an improvement but still requires the handler to have specific handle code for each of the different packet types.

So I was wandering is it possible to have it so that the received data is an object that has some code in it that has a method name of Say Handle packet and then  have the handler not need to know the type of packet/class that was received and have it just call the handle packet method. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

If this has been answered before I am sorry I just didn't know what this was called so my google searched where not helping.

Comment: Your explanation is pretty bad and I am not quite sure whether I understood your problem correctly. If I did, you might want to take a look at [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: what kind of data stream is this? it seems it is not real time positioning (or you'd use udp, instead of tcp) - if each packet invokes an operation you might be better served with an higher level API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158530/unity3d-xml-rpc-and-c-sharp

Comment: Be careful of how you do this:
"So I was wandering is it possible to have it so that the received data is an object that has some code in it that has a method name of Say Handle packet and then have the handler not need to know the type of packet/class that was received and have it just call the handle packet method."

Your instinct leads you to highly couple the code, and there are many resources you can read that will help explain why this is a bad idea. Suffice it to say, you want to pass data, and be able to change your mind later about how you handle that. Don't put in method names, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use polymorphism.  You need to create a base type called say Packet and then have the other packet types inherit Packet.  The Packet class will have the method called Handle so that all of the inherited classes will too.  That way you can call handle for all types of packets and the different types of packets can handle it differently.  See [this article from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more information on inheritance in java.

Comment: If `Packet` only defines a method (which most likely will be `abstract`), you can make it an interface.